# Creating a defining dictionary in python (glossary and input)

Tags: python, json, database, dictionary

I already have all the code done, I am just needing help on how I can get all my words, I have previously done databases before with countries, currencies, and leaders of the world, ect... but now I need definitions, can someone point me in the right way?

````
CCCdatbase = [
 {
   "country": "Afghanistan",
   "capital": "Kabul",
   "currency": "Afghani",
   "language": "Dari Persian; Pashto",
   "leader": "Amrullah Saleh",
   "k2": ""
 },
]

#except like this:

dictionary = [
    {
        "word": 'dog',
        "definition": "worse than cats"
    }
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

Why not

````
dictionary = [
    {
        'dog': 'worse than cats',
        'cat': 'feline...'
    }
]```
````

Comment: I was intending to find a database with all words in the dictonary and definition, and I finally figured that was stupid when I downloaded all words starting in "a" (litterally 20k lines of code). So I'm using an NLTK library, thanks for the answer though!